# Compile error when overloading operator<< with template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces, operator-overloading, name-lookup

I'm trying to use the stl copy () to print the key-value pair in a map. The code is as follows:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>

using namespace std;
//compile error if I comment out "namespace std"
namespace std {    
template<typename F, typename S> 
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const pair<F,S>& p) {
  return os << p.first << "\t" << p.second << endl;
}
}

int main() {
  map<int, int> m;
  fill_n(inserter(m, m.begin()), 10, make_pair(90,120));
  copy(m.begin(), m.end(), ostream_iterator<pair<int,int> >(cout,"\n"));
}
```

I'm trying to overload operator<<. The problem is that the code won't compile unless I surround the definition of the overloaded operator<< with `namespace std`. I think it is due to the name lookup mechanism of C++, which I still have trouble understanding. Even if I define non-template version like this:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const pair<int,int>& p) {
    return os << p.first << "\t" << p.second << endl;
}
```

It still won't compile. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: [Example of the error](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3MJn1M$1)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is with [argument-dependent name lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup) (ADL). The compiler is searching for an implementation of `operator<<` in `namespace std`, as both `ostream` and `pair` are in that namespace. You should make a wrapper that forwards to `operator<<` from the correct namespace:

```
template<class T>
struct ostreamer {
  ostreamer(const T& value) : reference(value) {}
  const T& reference;
  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, const ostreamer& value) {
    return stream << value.reference;
  }
};
```

Then just use `ostream_iterator<ostreamer<pair<const int, int>>>` instead of `ostream_iterator<pair<int, int>>`. Note that because `ostreamer` stores by reference and not by value, you can’t rely on the implicit conversion from `pair<const int, int>` to `pair<int, int>` anymore. You could change `ostreamer` to store by value, but as it is, it has no overhead, and I think it’s better to be explicit anyway.

Comment: Actually it is only safe to overload stuff in the std namespace if it involves a user defined type (i will try and find a reference to the spec later). As it stands neither the OP or your example do that.

Comment: @Jon Thank you for your reply! Does that mean the compiler ONLY look up the function in the std namespace, and nowhere else? How about other places like the current translation unit?

Comment: @John5342 I'd like to know the rationale behind "Actually it is only safe to overload stuff in the std namespace if it involves a user defined type". I think the `pair` construct here is kinda like a user defined type, the operator<< does not know how to output a pair, just like it does not know how to output a user defined type.

Comment: @rialmat: Yes. When overloads of the function (`operator<<`) exist in the same namespace as the class (`std::pair`), and the call site occurs within that namespace scope (`std::ostream_iterator`), *no* other candidates are considered.

Comment: @Jon Well first if all the standard is quite clear that you should not define anything in the std namespace except in specific circumstances. The reasoning is imagine a future standard where they provide that overload. Your function would cause compilation failures. If the overload involves a user defined type then it can never conflict.

Comment: @John5342: Alright, I’ve removed that part of the answer. There is an alternative, anyway.

Comment: The reference as promised: (17.6.4.2.1/1) `The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it adds declarations or definitions to namespace std or to a namespace within namespace std unless otherwise specified. A program may add a template specialization for any standard library template to namespace std only if the declaration depends on a user-defined type and the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template and is not explicitly prohibited.`. That's C++11 but the previous standard had a similar section (17.4.3.1/1?).

Comment: @JonPurdy The updated answer seems a little bit wordy to me. I wonder what is the most idiomatic way of writing an overloaded operator<< in this case?

Comment: @rialmat: Sorry, I don’t think it can be improved. The overload has to either be in the `std` namespace—which is disallowed by the standard—or be forwarded into `std`—which is what my answer shows how to do.